# CUDA PTX f32.f32 texture read

Tags: cuda, textures, ptx

Is it possible to read from a CUDA texture using a floating point index directly, e.g. can I perform a texture fetch using `tex.1d.v4.f32.f32`.

This appears to save two instructions when looking at the `.ptx` files and this is reflected in an increased performance when benchmarking. However, the rather critical downside is that, while this appears to run without issue, it does not produce the desired results.

The code below demonstrates the issue:

```
#include "cuda.h"
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>

//create a global 1D texture of type float
texture<float, cudaTextureType1D, cudaReadModeElementType> tex;

//below is a hand rolled ptx texture lookup using tex.1d.v4.f32.f32
__device__
float tex_load(float idx)
{
    float4 temp;
    asm("tex.1d.v4.f32.f32 {%0, %1, %2, %3}, [tex, {%4}];" :
        "=f"(temp.x), "=f"(temp.y), "=f"(temp.z), "=f"(temp.w) : "f"(idx));
    return temp.x;
}

//Try to read from the texture using tex1Dfetch and the custom tex_load
__global__ void read(){
    float x = tex1Dfetch(tex,0.0f);
    float y = tex_load(0.0f);
    printf("tex1Dfetch: %f    tex_load: %f\n",x,y);
}

int main()
{
    //create a vector of size 1 with the x[0]=3.14 
    thrust::device_vector<float> x(1,3.14);
    float* x_ptr = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&x[0]);

    //bind the texture
    cudaBindTexture(0, tex, x_ptr, sizeof(float));

    //launch a single thread single block kernel
    read<<<1,1>>>();
    cudaUnbindTexture(tex);
    return 0;
}
```

I've tried this on a couple of cards (K40, C2070) and with a couple of CUDA versions (6.0,7.0), but on all I get the same output:

```
tex1Dfetch: 3.140000    tex_load: 0.000000
```

Is this possible or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: Why are you using the `v4` variant for? Is that accidental or deliberate?

Comment: There is no other choice. For 1d texture lookups that are not using FP16, the texture load always returns a 4-element vector of 32-bit values. See here: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/#texture-instructions-tex

Comment: Indeed. You learn something new everyday. I had only ever written PTX for surface access, where there are `.none`, `.v2`, and `.v4` modifiers, I just assumed the standard texture instructions would be the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using an unsupported instruction for a texture which is bound to linear memory with the default `cudaReadModeElementType` read mode. If you rewrite your function like this:

```
__device__
float tex_load(int idx)
{
    float4 temp;
    asm("tex.1d.v4.f32.s32 {%0, %1, %2, %3}, [tex, {%4}];" :
        "=f"(temp.x), "=f"(temp.y), "=f"(temp.z), "=f"(temp.w) : "r"(idx));
    return temp.x;
}
```

ie. pass an integer index to the texture unit, not a float, I think you will find that it will work correctly. You would need to have a texture with a filtering read mode to use `tex.1d.v4.f32.f32`.

Comment: For a read mode of `cudaReadModeElementType`, no filtering is performed, and the only valid coordinate type is an integer index. You will find that `tex1DFetch` will be emitting `tex.1d.v4.f32.s32`in this case as well.